# WebLogic BEA-290015 Domain wide secret mismatch

Tags: weblogic

I get the following error when trying to deploy an application to a WebLogic domain:

```
<BEA-290015> <Domain wide secret mismatch>
```

The server can also be running, and the server will deploy or be marked as deferred deploy but will not really be running when monitored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our situation was that the managed server in question had a time synchronization issue. The server had drifted away from the admin server (and other managed servers) by several minutes.

Stopping ntpd, synchronizing ntpd, then restarting the ntpd service solved the issue. On RHEL7:

```
sudo systemctl stop ntpd
sudo ntpd -gq
sudo systemctl start ntpd
```

Stopping the managed server and restarting same cleared it up and the application ran on all servers.